# Python codes for below questions

Tags: python-3.x

Takes two numbers m and n as parameters and prints all possible strings of length n where each character is a digit from 0 to m.

> Note - Do not use Python’s itertools library for the same.

**Output:**
**Test1:**  n = 2, m = 1.
00
01
10
11

**Test2:** n = 2, m = 2
00
01
02
10
11
12
20
21
22

Comment: Please help me to code for this question

Comment: I tried like this, a="01"; for i in range(Len(a)): for j in range (Len(a)): print (a[i]+a[j])

Comment: I want to know how can I write code for using those inputs

Comment: @higovind You need to read comment formatting documents. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Thanks for the information@Byeongguk Gong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is here: use recursion.

```
def combine(p, q):
    if (p > 0):
        combine(p - 1, q);
    if (q > 0):
        combine(p, q - 1);
    print(str(p) + str(q) + " ");

combine(2, 3);
```